# How to store userdetails like password and username etc

Tags: java, android, sql, messenger

I'm building an Android Messenger with a Java-Server.

Obviously Users need to LogIn. How do I store the password and Username and how do I check it when a user tries to login?
With regards to Security I assume just using a Hashmap is not really a good idea.
On the other hand looking at performance I'm asking myself if i should use a SQL database(or similar). And how is security handled there?

I dont think using Java for the server is the way to do this professionally due to performance etc. but I already know Java and its just a learning project.

Comment: Are you want to achieve Server-Client connection in android app?

Comment: yes, i have a java server running and connet to the server from within the android app.

Comment: try this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a server, let them handle the authentication for you. Unless you are secure and know what you are doing, you do not want to store users authentication info yourself.

I strongly recommend using [Android Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) There are several tutorials out there for this, but [this one is my favorite](https://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)

---

**Edwin's addition:**

If you are using your own authentication and server: send authentication info **only after it's hashed/encrypted**, then decrypt server-side. Also, this image might contribute to the [general idea of this kind of flow](http://doc.norang.ca/sequence.png)

Comment: The URL you provided not opening seems it was mistake!

Comment: Would just like to add: send authentication info only when it's hashed/encrypted, then decrypt server-side. Also, [this image](http://doc.norang.ca/sequence.png) might contribute to the general idea for this kind of flow.

Comment: well, i am using a server... the server i write myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use username password encryption method easily
try this :

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Encryption {

    public static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING="UTF-8";
    static BASE64Encoder enc=new BASE64Encoder();
    static BASE64Decoder dec=new BASE64Decoder();

    public String base64encode(String text){
        try {
            String rez = enc.encode( text.getBytes( DEFAULT_ENCODING ) );
            return rez;
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) {
            return null;
        }
    }//base64encode

    public  String base64decode(String text){

        try {
            return new String(dec.decodeBuffer( text ),DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            return null;
        }

    }//base64decode



    public  String xorMessage(String message, String key){
        try {
            if (message==null || key==null ) return null;

            char[] keys=key.toCharArray();
            char[] mesg=message.toCharArray();

            int ml=mesg.length;
            int kl=keys.length;
            char[] newmsg=new char[ml];

            for (int i=0; i<ml; i++){
                newmsg[i]=(char)(mesg[i]^keys[i%kl]);
            }//for i
            mesg=null; keys=null;
            return new String(newmsg);
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            return null;
        }
    }//xorMessage
}
```

**then call method**

```
public String getEncryptWord(String txt) {
    return new Encryption().base64encode(txt);
}
```

**At the controller class**

```
 String password = authenticationController.getEncryptWord(user.getPassword());
```

now you can save the **password**; it's encrypted and secure

**Then when the login method you can check it this way**

```
 public User login(String username, String password) {
    String userPassword = authenticationController.getEncryptWord(password);
    System.out.println("User Pass : "+userPassword);
    User user = userDAOController.searchUserByEmail(username);
    System.out.println("DB Pass : "+user.getPassword());
    User returnUser;
    if(userPassword.equals(user.getPassword())){
        System.out.println("user");
        returnUser =  userDAOController.login(username, userPassword);
    }else{
        returnUser = null;
    }
    return  returnUser;
}
```

i think it will help
thanks.........